# Identifying the ideal generated by the variety $V(y^2-x^3)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am having trouble showing the following result:

> Suppose that $k$ is an infinite field and consider the affine variety $V(y^2-x^3)$. If $I(V)$ denotes the ideal of all polynomials vanishing on $V$, then $I(V) = (y^2-x^3)$.

The inclusion $(y^2-x^3) \leq I(V)$ is immediate, and if $k$ were algebraically closed for example, then the reverse inclusion would be trivial by the Nullstellensatz. But since $k$ is only assumed to be infinite, this is no good, and this is where I am stuck. Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $(y^2 - x^3) \subsetneq I(V)$ then there exists an element in $I(V)$ of the form $f(x)y + g(x)$.  Given any $a \in k$ the pair $(a^2, a^3) \in V$ so it is a solution to $f(x)y + g(x)$.  Also $(a^2, -a^3)$ is a solution for all $a \in k$.  Use these to show first that $f = 0$ because it has infinitely many roots.  Then show that $g = 0$.

You need to assume that the characteristic of $k$ is not $2$ for this argument to work.  When the characteristic of $k$ is $2$ the statement is not true.  For example when $k = \mathbb F_2$ we have $y + x \in I(V)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $char(k) \neq 2.$ Let $f(x,y) \in I(V),$ view it as an element in $k[x][y].$ Verify that there are $g(x,y),h(x),k(x)$ s.t. $f(x,y)=(y^2-x^3)g(x,y)+yh(x)+k(x).$ Now parameterize all points of $V$ by $t,$ i.e. $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)=(x,y).$ Use the assumption on $k$ being infinite to show that $yh(x)+k(x) \equiv 0.$